# tsc generate useless d.ts file when using high order function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to generate d.ts for my library. Here is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/typings",
    "target": "es5",
    "diagnostics": true,
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "typings/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And here is source code:

```
// script.ts
import { Application } from "../application";
export class ScriptType { }
export function createScript(ScriptConstructor: typeof ScriptType) {
    return (app: Application) => {
        // do something;
        return ScriptConstructor;
    }
}

// orbitCamera.ts
import { createScript, ScriptType } from "../script";
class OrbitCamera extends ScriptType { }
export default createScript(OrbitCamera);
```

When I call `tsc` to generate `d.ts`, I got the following result:

```
$ cat dist/typings/scripts/camera/orbitCamera.d.ts
import { ScriptType } from "../script";
export declare class OrbitCamera extends ScriptType {
...
}
declare const _default: (app: import("../../../../../../../Users/u/Projects/p/src/application").Application) => typeof ScriptType;
export default _default;
```

This is useless and when I reference this `d.ts` file in other project, it will throw `Cannot find name 'import'`.

So how can I solve this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using 2.9 in both the source and the target project ? `import` is only supported on `2.9` and above.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, I am using tsc `2.9.2`. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Rollback to tsc 2.9.1, everything works again.